# token validation using OAUTH2 Cognito configuration parameters in .net core web api

Tags: oauth-2.0, .net-core, amazon-cognito, asp.net-core-webapi

I am running Web API in .net core 2.1 and i need to validate the incoming JWT token that is stored in the incoming requests. 
The token was generated from an OAUTH 2 IDP and inserted by my client in its requests to my Web API.
The OpenID configuration I can get from cognito is the following:

```
{
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize",
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
    "issuer": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx",
    "jwks_uri": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json",
    "response_types_supported": ["code", "token", "token id_token"],
    "scopes_supported": ["openid", "email", "phone", "profile"],
    "subject_types_supported": ["public"],
    "token_endpoint": "https://xxxxxxx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token",
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": ["client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post"],
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://xxxxxxxx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo"
}
```

I would like to use the .net core Web API "standard" way of managing this task implementing in the startup.cs the following:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             // Clock skew compensates for server time drift.
             // We recommend 5 minutes or less:
             ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
             // Specify the key used to sign the token:
             IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
             RequireSignedTokens = true,
             // Ensure the token hasn't expired:
             RequireExpirationTime = true,
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             // Ensure the token audience matches our audience value (default true):
             ValidateAudience = true,
             ValidAudience = "api://default",
             // Ensure the token was issued by a trusted authorization server (default true):
             ValidateIssuer = true,
             ValidIssuer = "???????"
         };
```

How can I use/match the congnito parameters in my Web API token validation parameters? In particular how can I load the IssuerSigningKey, the ValidIssuer and the ValidAudience?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I solved the token signature validation check, inserting the following inside the "ConfigureServices" method in "Startup.cs"

...

```
IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>("*PutHereCognitoOpenIdWellKnownConfigurationURL*", new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());          
Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> t = configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
t.Wait();
OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = t.Result;
```

....

the previous statements returned me the IssuerSigningKeys, so I also inserted the following:

...

```
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        RequireExpirationTime = true,
                        RequireSignedTokens = true,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = false,
                        IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys
                    };

                });
```

...

and then I invoked the "app.UseAuthentication();" inside the Configure method.
Finally, I put the [Authorize] decoration before each of the involved Web API method